# Updating User Meta from Custom Post Field Upon Publish Not Working

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, user-meta, publish

I'm trying to get the user_meta to be updated based on the custom post field type. However the information won't transfer if the new post is published by a user through a frontend form.

Currently it only works if you update a listing via the front end form, or publish/edit a post via the backend of wordpress.

```
function update_package_id($post_id) {
$post = get_post($post_id);
$author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
$author_email = $author->user_email;
$package_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'package_pid', true  );
$user_id = $author->ID;
update_user_meta($user_id, 'package_type', $package_id);

if (function_exists( 'AC_OnUpdateUser' )) {
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
AC_OnUpdateUser( $user->ID, $user, FALSE );
}
}

add_action( 'publish_place', 'update_package_id' );
```

The second function fires the information into mailchimp. Am I using the wrong action in wordpress?

Comment: I am not sure about the above hook, can you try `save_post` instead and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response I went for an alternative option see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So the theme I used was not firing `add_action( 'publish_place', 'update_package_id' );`
or any of it's variations e.g. `save_post`

So I created a custom hook in the functions.php file of the theme which got the post id from the url (see `$_REQUEST['pid']`) here's what it looked like:

```
function update_package_id() {
$postinfo = $_REQUEST['pid'];
$post = get_post($postinfo);
$author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
$author_email = $author->user_email;
$package_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'package_pid', true  );
$user_id = $author->ID;
update_user_meta($user_id, 'package_type', $package_id);

if (function_exists( 'AC_OnUpdateUser' )) {
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
AC_OnUpdateUser( $user->ID, $user, FALSE );
}} add_action( 'updateusermet', 'update_package_id' );
```

This was then called through `do_action('updateusermet');` on the post submitted success page at the bottom before `get_sidebar();`

I hope that helps someone